# How to get selected file path from HTML input tag in php?

Tags: php, html

I need the selected file path(file that is being chosen by user).

For example, if I selected a file from directory F:\user\myfolder\document.docx, then this whole path should be shown.

I have used this :

```
$handle = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
echo $handle;
```

but this is giving something like this C:\xampp2\tmp\phpCECF.tmp, as this is not my current selected file path.

I have searched a lot, but can't find any solution.

Thank You.

Comment: you do not need the user's file path. it is useless information to you. save the file wherever you want to save it on the server. if you let the user set where you save it on your server, it would open a security hole. hence why browsers don't send this to you

Comment: ohkkkk, thanx a lot for this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You - as a web application - don't have access to the file system of the user.
The upload form in the browser however takes the file from the user's file system and it gets uploaded to a temp location `$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']` on your server's file system.

> $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'] : The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

Then you'll need to use the PHP method `move_uploaded_file()` to rename it and store it in the final location on the server file system.

More information on PHP file upload using HTML forms: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php